# Adding a JMenuItem to JMenuBar to create a toggle button in menu

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: image description]

The image means I want to put some button, like `JMenuItem`, into the application menu bar (`JMenuBar`) to allow toggling some operation. So I wrote such code:

```
        // Start button
        JMenuItem startbut = new JMenuItem();
        startbut.setText("Start");
        startbut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ToggleAction();
            }
        });
        menuBar1.add(startbut);
```

But it doesn't act as expected:

[image: image description]

Especially the white background is disturbing and looks broken.

Java GUI libraries have thousands options so I think there must be more valid way to do this. What should I do?

Comment: Just a suggestion, what if you use a `JToolBar` adding a `JToggleButton` to it? I wouldn't mess too much with menu bars since these are kind of singular components.

Comment: Man, that's nice! It actually works and I even like that it doesn't look like ordinary menu item: ![screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hB568.png)

Comment: @dic19 JMenuBar is container with BoxLayout

Comment: @mKorbel You are right. I was talking about some rendering issues on menus [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28768587/1795530) but of course we can add toggle buttons directly to the menu bar, as I think OP just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just summarizing the discussion in comments, you can add a `JToggleButton` to the menu bar instead of adding a `JMenuItem`, like this:

```
Action toggleAction = new AbstractAction("Start") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton)e.getSource();
        if (button.isSelected()) {
            button.setText("Stop");
            // Start the action here
        } else {
            button.setText("Start");
            // Stop the action here
        }
    }
};

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
menuBar.add(new JMenu("Settings"));
menuBar.add(new JToggleButton(toggleAction));
```

As @mKorbel pointed out the menu bar is a container so we can add components to it, not just `JMenu`.

[image: JToggleButton in a JMenuBar]

On the other hand using `JToolBar` instead of menu bar is another option. From an end-user point of view buttons placed in a tool bar are more natural than those placed in a menu bar so it might worth to consider this approach. Something like this will make it:

```
JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
toolBar.add(new JButton("Settings"));
toolBar.add(new JToggleButton(toggleAction)); // Here 'toggleAction' is the same than the previous one
```

This snippet will produce an outcome similar to the menu bar:

[image: JToggleButton in a JToolBar]

#### Note

Please note that menu bars has to be added to the top-level container (`JFrame` or `JDialog`) using the appropriate `setJMenuBar(...)` method. This is different than `JToolBar` which has to be added to the content pane like any other component. See [this related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21660699/1795530).